# Is there a way to not allow anyone to flushAll in redis?

Tags: redis

I am looking at a project to persist data realtime and am considering Redis. 
Issue I see with it is that anyone can issue a command to drop all the data  at once

How not to allow user to issue such a command before everything is persisted successfully.

Answer (score 4):

You can use rename-command in your config. According to the security section of [redis.conf](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/5.0/redis.conf):

```
# Command renaming.
#
# It is possible to change the name of dangerous commands in a shared
# environment. For instance the CONFIG command may be renamed into something
# hard to guess so that it will still be available for internal-use tools
# but not available for general clients.
#
# Example:
#
# rename-command CONFIG b840fc02d524045429941cc15f59e41cb7be6c52
#
# It is also possible to completely kill a command by renaming it into
# an empty string:
#
# rename-command CONFIG ""
#
# Please note that changing the name of commands that are logged into the
# AOF file or transmitted to replicas may cause problems.
```

Comment: Disabling  specific command is suitable solution. But keep in mind, when you are using Amazon's Elastic cache to host ur redis clusters, it doesn't provide direct access to redis.conf and also it doesn't provide a redis configuration parameter for rename-command.

Answer (score 2):

On top of renaming the command, as explained in **@Leisen Chang**'s answer, in the soon-to-be-released version 6 of Redis, [ACL](https://redis.io/topics/acl) (shorts for Access Control List) will be introduced.

ACL allows you to create users and assign them with permissions for calling commands and/or accessing key patterns. For example, here's how you'd create a user that can do everything except `FLUSHALL`:

```
redis> ACL SETUSER myuser on >mypass +@all -flushall
```