# Redis Sentinel Rename-Command Ignored

Tags: redis

I am trying to limit the allowed privileges for external redis sentinel users by renaming critical commands as follow:

```
sentinel rename-command mymaster FAILOVER failover-secret
```

However, the configurations are being ignored, and I still can trigger the renamed command using the original name:

```
127.0.0.1:26379> sentinel failover mymaster
OK
```

Redis Version:

```
Redis server v=6.0.9 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64 build=e874f7259751a389
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to put this in your Redis server's config file as opposed to setting it via CLI. It sounds like setting it this way either only applies to that connection (so other connections won't have that config change) or it only persists until the server restarts. Putting it in the config file would persist for all connections, and across restarts.

Another option if you're using Redis v6 (or can upgrade to v6) is to create separate users and specify the available commands per user. This option is discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59091693/2307873).